# two relations over two tables

Tags: sql, android-activity, process, double, relation

I have a problem with a database design I am trying to complete in sql server management in a diagram.

I have an process table and an activity table.

A process can call multiple activities, however an activity can only be called by one process at a time (one to many relation).
However in my second scenario an activity can also call one process at a time and a process can thus only be called by one activity. (one to one relation)

What is the best way to design these tables around this principal but also track who called who?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add activityID to process, and ProcessID to activity, that way you have the 2 relationships 1 - M that you are describing

Maybe call them something like CalledByProcessID (activity) and CalledByActivityID ( process

Answer (score 0):

To answer

> track who called who

Sounds to me like you need a third table to log calls, including ID of activity/process called,  ID of activity/process that did the calling, time started, time finished etc.

Also, enforcing

> an activity can only be called by one process **at a time**

and

> an activity can also call one process **at a time**

could be done by adding fields to the activity table, called_by_processID and calling_processID, which would need to be updated at start of call and emptied at end of call.

Alternatively, leave that functionality in the log table and only allow that activity/process call when the corresponding previous call has finished. Slightly more complicated logic but better normalisation.